# running my node app from systemd - can't call execFile (works when running from pm2)

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

On a raspberry Pi running raspian,
I have a small node+express app that is calling an external python script in order to trigger a relay.

When booting the app **using pm2 everything works**. When running the app by starting it as a systemd service the web server works, but the script is never called.

How must I configure a service to have this working?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const { execFile } = require('node:child_process');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'DoorMan' });
});

/* GET trigger door. */
router.get('/open', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('open', { title: 'Door is open' });
  // res.render('index', { title: 'DoorMan' });
    const child = execFile('python3', ['/home/johnny/app/bin/door.py'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    
  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

I have tried setting up pm2 so it should reboot on maschine reboot but I problems making that work as well and I would rather like to stick to one method of controlling processes.

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake was in the .service-file I was calling

`ExecStart=node /home/johnny/app/bin/www`

That works for pm2 which has my paths, but in the service file it's going to get old node version ~12

Calling full path to my node made it work:

`ExecStart=/home/johnny/.fnm/node-versions/v18.12.1/installation/bin/node /home/johnny/app/bin/www`